# Using XDMF to read HDF5 metadata

Tags: xml, hdf5, paraview

I have data that is stored in a HDF5 file that I wish to plot using Paraview. I have successfully been able to plot my data, however I would like to access the metadata (hdf attribute) within the selected dataset and I am unsure how to extract that information using XDMF format.

Answer (score 1):

ParaView support XDMF format. Just open your file.